# Ads slowing my Windows Phone app perfomance

Tags: c#, xaml

I am developing a windows phone app and i have decided to include ads in my app. Once i include the ads, the performance of my app is drastically reduced. My storyboard animations and my sounds are no longer smooth.

Is there any way to fix that?

I just added this code in my View:

```
 <ui:AdControl x:Name="MenuAdControl" 
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       ApplicationId="bb0f1a38-77b7-4939-aa71-c9edc7b201ed"
                       AdUnitId="11178977"
                       Visibility="Visible"
                       Width="480"
                       Height="80"/>
```

Comment: Cant help from this much code. Need more info like how you are loading ads etc.

Comment: Does the performance improve after a little time? i.e. after the AdControl control has made the initial connection and is showing Ads.